# Running multiple flask application on apache server

Tags: python, apache, flask

I have multiple flask application in `var/www/html` like `var/www/html/website`, `var/www/html/summary`,`var/www/html/sentiment`

Once I run all application successfully.

Then I added one more application for which I created conf file and restarted server.

After that all application stopped working, only `var/www/html/sentiment` opens.

I checked code in python, wsgi and conf file for other application is same as it is in sentiment.

Sentiment application code

flaskapp.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sentiment')
def hello_world():
  return 'Hello from Sentiment!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

flaskapp.wsgi

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/sentiment/')

from flaskapp import app as application
```

conf file - /etc/apache2/sites-available/sentiment.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName IP
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/sentiment/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/html/sentiment/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Summary application code
flaskapp.y

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/summary')
def hello_world():
  return 'Hello from Summary!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

flaskapp.wsgi

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/summary/')

from flaskapp import app as application
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/summary.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName IP
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/summary/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/html/summary/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Still when I open ip/sentiment it works but ip/summary gives

`The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: your apps are running on the same port, 
have you tried changing ports for each app in the `app.run(port=xxxx)`?

Comment: Yes, I tried giving different port in app.run() but still same issue. At a time only one application runs

Comment: However, when you use `<VirtualHost *:80>` , it seems you are overriding the default port for your apps. which means all your apps are running on port 80.
Have you tried with different ports on the config file ?

Comment: yes but please give some different port example

Comment: try ports from 5005 to 5010 to avoid any conflicts with anything you might have already ran.
you can just config each instance like :
`<VirtualHost *:5005>` and so one ..

Comment: i tried <VirtualHost *:81>

Comment: how about you append a port number for each of your apps on the app.run() :
for /sentiment :
`app.run(port=5005)` and  `<VirtualHost *:5005>`
and do the same for the others by changing port number, to 5006..etc
Because as you tested apps on port 80, 81, and 5000, these port might still be occupied by uncleaned instances.

Comment: when i run adding your solution   ip/sentiment its gives error                                                                    The requested URL /sentiment was not found on this server.

Comment: yes, you also need to change the server name, it won't work if you have the same server name on every config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your **WSGIScriptAlias** name.

`/` points to everything in the directory.

Give unique alias names to all applications.

***Example:***

Change `/` to `/app1` for **WSGIScriptAlias**

Change `/` to `/app2` for **WSGIScriptAlias**

in both the files.

Restart the server then.